# How to write output from Roslyn FxCopAnalyzers to disk using MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, roslyn, code-analysis, fxcop, roslyn-code-analysis

I have a .NET Core 2.0 project for which I would like to perform code analysis from the command line and write the output to disk.  Per the discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1313), I have referenced the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers Nuget package (enabled for both Debug and Release configurations).  I am running the following command from the command line:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Enterprise/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe"  /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=MyCodeAnalysisLogFile2.xml  /target:Build "C:/Source/TestProject/TestProject.sln"
```

From the resulting output, I can see that code analysis is being applied and rules are violating as expected.  However, no log file is being written to disk, and the `CodeAnalysisLogFile` property seems to have no effect.  I've also tried `CodeAnalysisOutputFile` to no avail.

I'd like to get an XML code analysis output just like in the old days.  How do I get the code analysis output written to disk when using the Roslyn compiler?